# Nslookup not showing the updated records. Cached?

Tags: domain-name-system, nslookup

In Linux server it does not show the updated entry which should be a public IP. I installed nscd and restarted it to see if it'll flush. Its a squid server, fyi

```
    nslookup subdomain.domain.com 
    Server:         10.80.80.80
    Address:        10.80.80.80#53

    Name:   subdomain.domain.com
    Address: 10.10.10.10
```

But in windows server it shows the correct entry (a public IP). They both use same DNS server.

```
    Server:         10.80.80.80
    Address:        10.80.80.80

    nslookup subdomain.domain.com 
    Name:   subdomain.domain.com
    Address: 185.185.185.185
```

DIG command output:

```
    dig subdomain.domain.com

    ; <<>> DiG 9.7.1-P2 <<>> mysubdomain.domain.com
    ;; global options: +cmd
    ;; Got answer:
    ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 64997
    ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

    ;; QUESTION SECTION:
    ;subdomain.domain.com. IN   A

    ;; ANSWER SECTION:
    subdomain.domain.com. 299 IN A      10.10.10.10
    subdomain.domain.com. 299 IN A      10.10.10.10
    subdomain.domain.com. 299 IN A      10.10.10.10

    ;; Query time: 197 msec
    ;; SERVER: 10.80.80.80#53(10.80.80.80)
    ;; WHEN: Thu Jun 11 10:45:39 2015
    ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 98
```

Comment: Are you sure? If nslookup say server: XXX this server it's server that put response. If cached DNS system, put Server: IP_DNS_CAHED_SYSTEM. Please try dig mydomain.com and put result

Comment: updated dig command output.

Comment: I think taht you has on binf.conf two diferents files for zone subdomain.domain.com... one for external network and other for internal. If same server respond diferents IP, ot's beacuse there're a config diferent. Esample --> view "internal" {} and view    "external" {}    on each view, there're a zone for subdomain.domain.com or domain.com with difrents values,

Comment: plase update your file named.conf or bind.conf  (option, views, and search domain afected)